# How can I show my activity as a dialog in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I am working on my first Android application, and am trying to style my activity. Ultimately, I would like for my activity to look the same as a dialog. I have given all my activities the `Theme.Dialog` style using the following code in my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/group"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
</application>
```

This gives my activities the "floating" appearance and the borders of a dialog, but not the styled title. The title just has the same color and appearance as the general dialog background, not the "header" background and border as in a "real" dialog. Notice how in both examples the header has a nice border under it and in the second one, it has a gradient background.

Is there a way to make sure the title on my activity somehow inherits the system dialog title so as to effectively replicate the look of a dialog for my activity - in addition to the border and "float" which comes with the `Theme.Dialog` style?

Note that I do not want to call my activity as a dialog from another, I just want it to ***LOOK*** like a dilaog, even when it is loaded in response to an intent as per my manifest's intent-filters.

[image: Dialog Example 1]

[image: Dialog Example 2]

**ADD:** Is there perhaps some way I can have my activity, when it spins up in `onCreate()`, call some method to turn itself into an actual dialog? Keep in mind the activity still needs to be able to respond to intents from the system.

Comment: which dialog you want ? first one or second one in image.

Comment: They are both the result of calling the standard show-dialog methods. The second is the dialog as it appears themed with Samsung's TouchWiz UI, the first is as it appears themed by the skin I'm running in Cyanogenmod. Basically, I just want my activity to APPEAR AS IF it is a dialog as per whatever theme the user's device is running, the same as if I used AlertDialog.Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After deciding to look at ***what*** I wanted to do, instead of *how to do it* specifically, I found a different approach. I reasked my question looking for approach ideas instead of implementation ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810931/how-can-i-have-a-home-screen-shortcut-launch-a-dialog). GalDude33 helped me figure out how to achieve what I wanted. His answer there was the answer to this Q.

Comment: Sure, but the problem with this approach is, that the result has no properties of Activity. E.g. you can't show ActionBar in your dialog.

Comment: I will really admit that not bring able to use the ActionBar is the biggest disadvantage... and having to roll my own look-alike toolbar. If you can show me a way to get dialog functionality while also being able to use the ActionBar, I'd be very happy!

Comment: I found out, that you can change activity's dimension in onCreate(...) method, however I don't know how to make black borders semitransparent, so that it looks like dialog: `WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();  
params.height = 300;  
params.width = 100;
getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
getWindow().setAttributes(params); `

Answer (score 4):

A Dialog theme can be customised by specifying it as parent, in styles.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
            <item name="android:background">#ffdddddd</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

If you give a different color to the background of customized dialog style and the layout(add `android:background="#ffffffff"` under layout header in your main.xml file), it would give a system dialog like look.

Hope this helps..

Missed to mention:
Refer to the customized theme in your manifest as below:

```
android:theme="@style/MyDialogTheme"
```

Comment: Well, I am already using the `Theme.Dialog` style on my activity, but it only gives you the floating appearance, and the border around your activity. It does not style the activity's title bar. I don't necessarily want to customize the dialog look, I am rather trying to make my activity look exactly like the intrinsic dialog (however that may look as per the user's phone's theme).

Answer (score 2):

You can do as follow..

create a layout for your dialog and set in as below.

```
Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(MainScreen.this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);

mDialog .requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

mDialog .setContentView(R.layout.dialoglayout);
mDialog .show();
```

Comment: I would need to add this in code in another activity though, no? My activity responds directly to launcher intents (shortcuts created on the homescreen), and I want it to look like a dialog when it is called by the system for those intents, or directly through the launcher, also.