# Using support library v4 fragments in custom DialogPreference

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, dialog-preference

I'm trying to implement custom `DialogPreference`, whose layout will use fragments. An app should support `API 10` (which does not natively support fragments).

In order to work with fragments I need to get an instance of the `android.support.v4.FragmentManager` (normally usually being received from support FragmentActivity using `getSupportFragmentManager`).

I have no idea how to get `android.support.v4.FragmentManager` within DialogPreference. Any clue is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling the dialog from an `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`  you should be able to do a type cast in your `DialogPreference` class, to get the Support-FragmentManager:

```
(android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity)getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager()
```

... if that's not possible, another solution would be to [launch an activity that looks like a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738264/how-can-i-show-my-activity-as-a-dialog-in-android), and use your fragments there. [How to open an activity from a PreferenceScreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041292/launch-new-activity-from-preferenceactivity)

Comment: That's what I eventually did - launched an activity that looks like a dialog. Thanks